# Change JButton background color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton

This is what my code looks like:

```
//color selection (all First column element)
JButton A1 = new JButton("");
A1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
A1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
A1.setBounds(0, 288, 44, 29);
contentPane.add(A1);

JButton A2 = new JButton("");
A2.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
A2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
A2.setBounds(0, 316, 44, 29);
contentPane.add(A2);
```

No matter how I change it, it seems like there's an incompatible issue between color and button. I tried to use `setOpaque` and other methods but still did not work.

How to change the background color of a `JButton`?

Comment: **General Advice:** 1) Use the standard nomenclature for attribute names (start with a lower case letter). Also make them meaningful. `a2` might be a good attribute name for a square on a chessboard, is that what this is for? 2) [Edit] to add a [mre]. 3) Use. **Layouts!** 4) Consider using colored icons *instead* of setting the BG color. All the space can be removed from around them - the button itself can be made effectively invisible. 5) Leave GUI builders aside for the moment. To get the best of them, you first need to understand layouts and how to make a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" - most look and feels will, generally, ignore the background color when rendering the buttons and apply there own internal stylings, for example, on MacOS. this...

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("Test");
b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
add(b1);

JButton b2 = new JButton("Test2");
b2.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
add(b2);
```

will produce this...

[image]

In most cases, the button is transparent by default (in my experience), so instead we need to do something like...

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("Test");
b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
b1.setOpaque(true);
add(b1);

JButton b2 = new JButton("Test2");
b2.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
b2.setOpaque(true);
add(b2);
```

which would produce...

[image]

This is because the look and feel is applying it's own styling (via the `borderPainted` property)

So, if instead, we did something like...

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("Test");
b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
b1.setOpaque(true);
b1.setBorderPainted(false);
add(b1);

JButton b2 = new JButton("Test2");
b2.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
b2.setOpaque(true);
b2.setBorderPainted(false);
add(b2);
```

we'd end up with...

[image]

Sooo, technically, we've changed the background of the button, but I don't know about you, this is not what I would really want.  There's no "simple" way you could change the background color of the "border" been used (at least not that I've found which is cross platform independent).  The "only" solution would would have is to create a new look and feel delegate which could some how provide the fill color for the button border and renderer it yourself, but that is a LOT of work if you want to use it across different platforms (and I've looked into trying to make one for MacOS and gave up, because MacOS has to be "different")

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the `setContentAreaFilled(false)` in order to apply your background colors to the `JButton`.

```
JButton A1 = new JButton("Test");
A1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
A1.setBounds(0, 288, 44, 29);
contentPane.add(A1);

JButton A2 = new JButton("Test2");
A2.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
A2.setBounds(0, 316, 44, 29);
contentPane.add(A2);
```